# Jackson custom deserializer dropped some fields inside the deserializer method

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a JSON object that needs to be deserialized in my use case. Also, I need to generate some fields value combining one or more attributes in the same JSON. So I chose Jackson deserialization and annotated the required fields with relevant deserialization classes like follow

```
@Getter
@ToString
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Product implements Serializable {

    @JsonProperty("item_name")
    @JsonDeserialize(using = ProductDeserializer.ItemName.class)
    private String itemName;
    
    @JsonProperty("item_code")
    @JsonDeserialize(using = CommonDeserializer.Trim.class)
    private String itemCode;
    
    @JsonProperty("demand_status")
    @JsonDeserialize(using = ProductDeserializer.DemandStatus.class)
    private boolean isDemandItem;
    
    @JsonProperty("upc")
    private long upcCode;
    
    @JsonProperty("store_condition") //multiple attributes uses, ex 'store_code'
    @JsonDeserialize(using = ProductDeserializer.StoreConditionDeserializer.class)
    private StoreCondition storeCondition;

    .....

}
```

Deserialization class for the `storeCondition` variable is as follows,

```
public static class StoreConditionDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<StoreCondition> {
    @Override
    public StoreCondition deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException {
        String stock_id = jp.getCodec().readValue(jp, JsonNode.class).asText();
        String store_code = jp.getCodec().readValue(jp, JsonNode.class).get("store_code").asText();
    
        /* I need to access several fields from the JSON to generate the object I need, 
           but some of them are missing here but they exist in the JSON input */
    
        //Also some logic, API calls, etc
    
        return ...;
    }
    
}
```

This is how my input JSON looks like

```
{
  "_id": 28463836,
  "item_name": "john product",
  "item_code": "doe code",
  "store_code": "T",
  "demand_status": "D",
  "upc": 874564847,
  "store_condition": "F",
  "location": "IR",
  "W_Code": "X3846"
}
```

If you take a look at the Pojo class, the last attribute annotated with `@JsonProperty("store_condition")`, which is also present in the above JSON. When the deserialization happens, it does not have this complete JSON object within the `deserialize` method, it only has the attributes after the `store_condition` attribute. But for my use case, I need to access the fields above that, for example, `store_code`. But since the `store_code` code is located before `store_condition`, the `store_code` does not available in the deserializer.

This is how I do the deserialization,

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Product product = mapper.convertValue(jsonInput, Product.class);
```

**Could someone explain why and how this happens? Also, a way to solve this.** 
I hope that my question and my requirement is clear. Feel free to drop a comment if you need any clarifications.

The Jackson library I used is `group: 'org.apache.beam', name: 'beam-sdks-java-extensions-json-jackson', version: '2.47.0'`

Answer (score 1):

the JsonParser is fetch data in sequence, when you invoke readValue, it get `F`, and the parser move its cursor to next token, so there is no method to access the store_code field that in the previous. so for your scenario, i think you could add custom deserializer for `Product` Class and maintaion all the field in your self, so you could no effect by the parse order.

Comment: Thank you for the information, I posted an answer. Could you take a look https://stackoverflow.com/a/76378976/8778025

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround solution for this, after we create the `ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();` pass the required values to it in the following way,

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
DeserializationConfig deserializationConfig = mapper.getDeserializationConfig();
DeserializationConfig modifiedConfig = deserializationConfig.withAttribute("mappingData", map);
mapper.setConfig(modifiedConfig);
```

Then access the passed information through the deserializer in this way,

```
public com.sysco.site_product.models.pisv2.Split deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException {
      Map<String, Object> inputJSONMap = (Map<String, Object>) context.getAttribute("mappingData");

......

}
```

Open for feedbacks!

Comment: what conent in you  field `map`

Comment: It is a Java Map containing several attributes in the input JSON payload required to do my need. Simply, integers, strings, and doubles.

Comment: so how does this relate to your access to the a `store_code`. i cann't understand this solution. could you post more detail.

Comment: Sure, when we pass the information in the above way, we can access that information from the deserialization method `DeserializationContext ` parameter. So I can pick the attribute and the value from the passed Map and perform the business logics.